# using custom formatter for highstock's yaxis labels formatter

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using custom formatter for yaxis labels of Highstock.
it works except as it should.
I want to it returns for example "15 bar" instead of "15000 bar" as when default formatter does.

Here is my snippet code:

```
yAxis.labels.formatter = "function(){return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, ',') +' " + portSetting.QuantityUnit + "'}";
```

tanks.

Comment: This question doesn't provide much useful information about the highstock custom labels formatter; it was asked because of an unrelated syntax problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [formatter](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis-labels--formatter) should be a function and it looks like you are assigning a string.

So instead of:

```
yAxis.labels.formatter = "function(){return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, ',') +' " + portSetting.QuantityUnit + "'}";
```

you should write a function like:

```
yAxis.labels.formatter = function () {
    return 
         Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, ',') + 
         ' "' + portSetting.QuantityUnit + '"';
};
```

Comment: i know that, the snippet code I've provided is a C# code and it renders in client without quotation marks.

Comment: OK, kind of hard to guess that when the question is tagged 'javascript'. If you are asking how to turn 15000 into 15? Just divide the value with 1000.